# How to modify a database command in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Alright, so I've been working on this project for the past year and I've never understood this one issue in crystal reports. (I'm using the crystal reports that comes with Visual Studio 2008)

Let's say I want to modify a database field nested in the command.

[image: Screenshot of the Command]

I right-click the command field and choose the database expert option from the context menu.

[image: Database expert option]

I then right-click the command once again and choose the Modify option.

[image: Modify option]

Here's where I always get stuck.. I enter the password (which is the same I use in the ConnectionString for my project) and click the finish button..

[image: Oracle connection window]

..only to be presented with the following error message, which translates to **"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"**

[image: Error message]

After some searching around I found this article : http://scn.sap.com/thread/3291225

The answer to the same problem that I'm getting was :

*You must install the Oracle Driver 64 if youe OS is 64 bits, and then install Oracle Driver 32 in the same home_oracle, this should be the home1. SAP just works with home1.
You must install the Oracle Client Administrator mode.
After that you must configure your ODBC driver to Oracle Home 1. Right now test if your ODBC connection is successful.
Your application should run in 32 bit mode.*

Unfortunately I'm connected to this computer remotely and am not authorized to install / uninstall drivers and applications.

My question is, is there another way that I can solve this issue so I can change that one field to a string?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just convert that field to a string in CR via `ToText()`?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I see there are 2 problems in your question.

1. The error you getting is nothing related to the datatype of the field you want to change. The present error is because You are trying to access the database for that uou need to have oracle client and you should create a ODBC connection then you will be able to make connection and can view query in crystal report.
2. To the extent I am aware you can't change the dataatype of a database field using the command in Crystal Report, but what you can do is instead of going to command, You can create one formula in crystal report and cast the number to string using `ToText`

Let me know if you need further more information

Comment: What do you mean "you can't change the datatype of any field..."?? There is a whole family of type conversion functions in CR.

Comment: @Ryan Yes you can do it in a formula but user is trying to change at query level.. yes I accept when you use a formula you can do it using totext but not at database query level

Comment: But you CAN change the data type in the query by using a command or expression. Just because this user can't make changes to the command doesn't mean that blanket statement is true. I'd suggest revising your second point to be more clear. As it stands, it's misinformation.